# How to set specific header color using the headerAttributes?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

According to [Kendo grid documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.headerAttributes), we are able to set the column's header attribute by using the headerAttributes:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [{
    field: "name",
    headerAttributes: {
      style: "text-align: right; font-size: 14px; color: red !important;"
    }
  }],
  dataSource: [ { name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe" } ]
});
```

It's working for most attributes but not for the color.  It does make sence since the color attribute of the `link` (k-link class) will have priority over the `th` color attribute.

However, I'm wondering if there's a workaround that would allow me to set the color for a specific header when I initialize the grid.  Right now, the only solution I might think of would be to set the `link` color after the grid is initialized.

Comment: Since 2022, kendo has fixed the problem by replacing the `<a>` header tags with `<span>` tags.  I'll leave my question here for those who are still working with older version of kendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than adding the inline styles which will get overridden without a lot of hacking why not use the headerTemplate like this:

```
  field: "ContactName",
  title: "Contact Name",
  width: 200, 
  headerTemplate:'<label class="greenHeader">Contact Name</label>'
```

Then have the appropriate css class in your style sheets like:

```
.greenHeader
    {
     color:green ;
    }
```

for an example see this dojo:

[Example of header template being used.](http://dojo.telerik.com/ImedA)